# OpenAPI and Lambda integration within API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, swagger, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, openapi

When I use CloudFormation to deploy an API with a Lambda integration, I'm able to dynamically link a Lambda function to an API method using standard CloudFormation syntax like `!Ref` and `!GetAtt`:

```
SomeMethod:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  Properties:
    HttpMethod: PUT
    Integration:
      Type: AWS_PROXY
      IntegrationHttpMethod: POST

#     this is defined during deployment
      Uri: !Join ["", ["arn:aws:apigateway:", !Ref "AWS::Region", ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/", !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn,  "/invocations"]]
      IntegrationResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
    ResourceId: !Ref APIResource
```

Now when I want to reference an external swagger file to define my API, which I can do via the `BodyS3Location` property on the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` object, I can't understand how to *dynamically* link the defined methods to a Lambda function.

[API as Lambda Proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-as-lambda-proxy-export-swagger-with-extensions.html) describes how to statically link a method to a Lambda function, i.e.

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
    "credentials": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/apigAwsProxyRole",
    "responses": { ... },

#   this is statically defined
    "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:Calc/invocations",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "requestTemplates": { ... },
    "type": "aws"
}
```

But if my Lambda function is part of the same CloudFormation stack (which it is and should be), and I want to deploy multiple instances, how can I dynamically integrate my API with Lambda? I can't use `!Ref` or `!GetAttr` because I'm outside of CloudFormation's context.